# Static list to be persisted between new instances of a class

Tags: .net, vb.net, static

I have a VB.NET Windows service which implements a timer that is fired each minute.
This timer calls a method, Execute. This method create an instance of a class MyClass and then invokes a method, DoWork, of that class. Within DoWork method, I check if myStaticList list exists. If static list does not exists(not initialized: nothing), then I create the static list and store some parameters. If static list exists then I read the values on it to do some work. I need myStaticList list to be persisted between new instance of MyClass. How can I do it? Below the code snippet.

```
Public Class MyService

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
         Dim serviceTimer As New Timer
         serviceTimer.Interval = 60000
         AddHandler serviceTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
         serviceTimer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
         Dim serviceTimer As Timer = source
         Try
             serviceTimer.Stop()
             Me.Execute()
         Catch ex As Exception
             ' Do something...
         Finally
             serviceTimer.Start()
         End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Execute()
        Dim p As New MyClass()
        p.DoWork()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class MyClass
    Static myStaticList As List(Of MyAnotherClass)

    Public Sub DoWork()
       ' Do the work
       If IsNothing(myStaticList) Then
          ' Create and do something with myStaticList, store values, etc.
       Else
          ' Do something with my existing myStaticList, read values and do something
       End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `Shared` is the keyword to associate an object with the class generally, rather than a specific instance.  You will need to use extreme caution to make sure that your workflow is appropriately protected by locks given that you are working with shared mutable state (you'll need to ensure that nothing but the code that constructs the list ever sees a partially-populated list, and you'll need to ensure that you don't try to construct the list in two places at once).  `Lazy` might help with this, it has some of the locking infrastructure in place.

Comment: Also, don't use IsNothing, that's a long-obsolete compatibility function from the VBA-versions of VB (where it was used to check on `Variant`s that might contain objects).  Use the `Is` and `IsNot` operators, e.g. `If myStaticList Is Nothing` or `If myStaticList IsNot Nothing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to store a `myStaticList` as a member of `MyService` as a private, non-static member.

<s>It will require to move a method which fills list to MyService.</s>
It will require instantiate list in a `MyService` and those list will be still available for changes in `MyClass`.

This list could be then passed into `MyClass` instance by constructor which will assign a list.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make the myStaticList not "Static" but "Shared":

```
Private Shared myStaticList As List(Of MyAnotherClass)
```

Actually it probably should not be called myStaticList after but rather mySharedList ;)

The list will be shared between all instances of MyClass and stay around after instances of MyClass die.